# How to handle transitive includes? (Triggering "Cannot declare constant warning" in julia-vscode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, dependencies, julia, include

I wrote some julia code in several files, where some files `include` others. At some point, I encountered the same file to be included multiple times due to "transitivity", i.e. I included another file, which includes that file, again.

Toy example:

```
# A.jl

struct A1
    a::Int
end

struct A2
    a::Int
end
```

```
# B.jl

include("A.jl")

struct B
    a::A
end
```

```
# C.jl

include("A.jl")
include("B.jl")

# Using a thing from B.jl
b=B(A1(1))

# Also need functionality A2 from A.jl not needed in B.jl
a2 = A2(2)

println(b)
```

This executes nicely (even without any warning). But julia for VS Code displays the warning `Cannot declare constant; it already has a value. Julia(CannotDeclareConst)`.

I understand that the second include can do unintended things. Also, I understand, I could fix this by not importing A.jl in C.jl.

But from another perspective it seems reasonable to import A.jl into C.jl, since functionality other than the one required in B.jl is required, and at some point in the future I could decide to not include A.jl into B.jl anymore, breaking the dependencies of C.jl in a way, which might be difficult to spot.

I could also split up A.jl into A1.jl and A2.jl, but I wouldn't like that for other reasons.

How would I keep these dependencies in a safe way (perhaps similar to header guards in C++) in julia. Can I somehow use modules for that?

Thanks already for your thoughts!

-------------- EDIT ----------------

Here's my current solution... I declare the `A` and `B` structs in separate modules (called `As` and `Bs` in corresponding files As.jl and Bs.jl):

```
# As.jl

module As
export A

struct A
    a::Int
end

end
```

```
# Bs.jl

module Bs
export B
using As

struct B
    b::A
end

end
```

No `include` anymore, only `using`. For the caller file:

```
# C.jl

using As
using Bs

a = As.A(1)
b = B(a)

println(a) # > A(1)
println(b) # > B(A(1))
```

This feels like the appropriate way to do it.

One drawback is that the VS Code Julia linter unfortunately does not fully support this case, yet. (You cannot jump to the definition of A when editing C.jl, for instance.) See [here](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/307).

Moreover, for the true use case, I am working on, I have the impression, that the start-up (=precompilation?) of the script takes much longer after introducing the module structure. For the toy example above, this isn't the case, though.

Comment: I think you should use the modules instead of includes for this (you even used import in the OP naturally).

Comment: If `C` includes `B` and `B` includes `A`, there `C` already includes `A`, right?

Comment: @DanGetz: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I posted my updated code above. Do you think that is an appropriate way to set this up? Also - I don't know, which version is more practical, because Julia for VS Code has problems with the clean one, which uses modules. See the edit.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer: Thanks for looking at this! Yes, that is true, and I could resolve it by omitting the include("A.jl") in C.jl in this case. But as I tried to explain, I would like to keep the dependency documented, so to say.